# Is there a way to identify available suites / components / arches of public APT repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, add-apt-repository

Some providers give base URL for a public APT repository and directory listing is forbidden for the HTTP file server. Is there a way to understand which suites / components /arches they provide?

Like to get the content of `dists/*` and then the content of `dists/<suite>/*`, then the content of `dists/<suite>/<component>/*`.

For the link `http://http.us.debian.org/debian/` I want to see the list:

```
stable stretch testing sid
```

then for given suite I want to see the list:

```
main contrib non-free
```

and then:

```
amd64 mips
```

Everything is in the path like:

```
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-arm64/
```

Example of the repo with closed directory listing is: https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com

Answer (score 1):

If you know the suite, and the repo is modern enough, the components and architectures will be in the `InRelease` file, e.g., http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-backports/InRelease (or the unsigned `Release` file for older repos):

```
% curl -sL http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-backports/InRelease | head -n 20
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

Origin: Debian Backports
Label: Debian Backports
Suite: bullseye-backports
Codename: bullseye-backports
Changelogs: https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/@CHANGEPATH@_changelog
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2022 14:18:28 UTC
Valid-Until: Sat, 24 Dec 2022 14:18:28 UTC
NotAutomatic: yes
ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes
Acquire-By-Hash: yes
No-Support-for-Architecture-all: Packages
Architectures: all amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
Components: main contrib non-free
Description: Debian 11 - Backports
SHA256:
 a46b4154da65694b056a9aab60e90f5615fb81629bd88b8204839c64bf89958e    86330 contrib/Contents-all
 52264b2b1e4abb6f8dd1c03894bf93ba7a794f25a10f0b9e0e287001780ff724    12849 contrib/Contents-all.diff/Index
```

But at least the suite needs to be known. I don't know of anyway to discover it from just the repo base URL.

Comment: Seems the tool should attempts to guess suites, from Debian / Ubuntu, other distros...

Answer (score 0):

There is limited support for selected APT databases, implementing madison CGI interface:

```bash
sudo apt install devscripts
rmadison emacs
rmadison -u debian emacs
rmadison -u ubuntu emacs
```

On the Debian WEB it is possible to query all registered sources in a single query:

https://qa.debian.org/madison.php?package=emacs&table=all&a=&c=&s=#

The output looks like:

```
 emacs | 45.0ubuntu1       | trusty           | all
 emacs | 46.1              | xenial           | all
 emacs | 47.0              | bionic           | all
 emacs | 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2 | focal/universe   | source, all
 emacs | 1:27.1+1-3ubuntu5 | jammy/universe   | source, all
 emacs | 1:27.1+1-3ubuntu5 | kinetic/universe | source, all
 emacs | 1:27.1+1-3ubuntu5 | lunar/universe   | source, all
```